# Can a single quote leads to XSS attacks?

Tags: javascript, xss

Can a single quote alone leads to cross site scripting attacks,if so can you please provide me an example?

One example is like:
javascript:alert('hi')
but here we are using : also along with quote.

Comment: Yes, it can. If you have one in the wrong place in your code, that can trigger all kinds of errors and might lead to an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: <a onmouseover=alert('xss')>[hover for details]</a>

Comment: We are also using '=','(',')' in your example,the question is if its possible with single quote only.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but there are XSS vectors that include single quotes and that don't include `javascript:`. For example:

```
<IMG SRC= onmouseover="alert('xxs')">
```

For a long list of examples, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but the problem is i have one user having a quote in his name and on the server side i have put the condition that if any user have special characters throw an error to prevent css attacks,so the question is if i exclude quote on server side and let the user pass,will it be safe?

Comment: If you're sanitizing your user input, then a single quote is a reasonable character to allow in a user's name. You can use the OWASP list to test your sanitizer. There are many out there that you can use, depending on what platform you are on (search for XSS sanitizer).

Answer (score 0):

Can a single quote alone lead to XSS? No. But single quotes are capable of terminating strings in many languages, for example: SQL.
The single quote you are refering to is the [classic example of](http://xkcd.com/327/) a [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

[There are many possible ways to perform XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet), which depend partly on the server software being used, and partly upon the client being more trusty than is sometimes wise.

XSS stands for cross-site scripting. The problem is that if someone- from an external source, outside of your control- was able to add script to your webpage, that script would be run there, with some -or all- associated privileges

Answer (score 0):

Yes. compare:

```
alert(
  eval(
    location.hash.slice(1) // '
// ^
  )
);
```

to

```
alert(
  eval(
    'location.hash.slice(1) // '
//  ^
  )
);
```

The first is very vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

The example you mentioned is the only common way that I'm aware of. In most other cases it's difficult to use single quotes to inject HTML, but not necessarily impossible (at least in some rare cases)

For example, with double quotes:

```
const customLink = `" onmouseover="alert()"`
const html = `<a href="${customLink}">click here!</a>`
```

will become:

```
<a href="" onmouseover="alert()">click here!</a>
```

However, with single quotes, you can't end the `href` attribute (at least as far as I know). So injecting HTML is more tricky. For example, the following would work, but probably isn't very common:

```
const customAttribute = `onmouseover='alert()'`
const html = `<a ${customAttribute}>click`
```